# Can't call function from public class in main ... "new types may not be defined in a return type"

Tags: c++, oop, object

I am trying to call a void function inside a public class, but I get errors I do not understand:

```
#include <iostream>
class Buttons
{
    public:
        Buttons()
        {
            short pushl;
            short *tail;
            cout << "Wally Weasel" << "/t";
            void init_sub(int x, int y);
        };
        ~Buttons()
        {
            cout << "Buttons has been destroyed!";
        };
}
int main(int args, char**LOC[])
{
    int z, a;
    Buttons::init_sub(z, a);
    return 2;
}
Buttons::void init_sub(int x, int y)
{
    cout << &x << &y;
}
```

NEWLY UPDATED CODE (STILL DOESN'T WORK):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Buttons
{
  public:
  Buttons()
  {
    short pushl;  // unused variable in Constructor: should be a member variable?
    short *tail;  // same
    cout << "Wally Weasel" << "/t";
  };

  ~Buttons()
  {
    cout << "Buttons has been destroyed!";
  }

 void init_sub(int z, int a);
};


int main(int args, char **LOC[])
{
    int z = 0;
    int a = 1;
    Buttons::init_sub(z, a);
    return 2;
}

void Buttons::init_sub(int x, int y)
{
    cout << &x << " " << &y;
}
```

Why can't I call the function?

Original error persisting: "new types may not be defined in a return type"

PS: I updated my code to match the present state of my situation - still the same error though.
 I have been struggling to no end with C++ - I am used to lower-level programming without so many semantics involved of syntax/structuring.

Comment: What is unclear about it?

Comment: There a little bit of mess, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Call the function in the class in the constructor.

Comment: If you indent your code it will be a lot clearer to everyone - including you.

Comment: I added the code tags to it initially. What do _you_ mean by indent?

Comment: Indent is a word with one meaning. He means that.

Comment: I added code tags ... why indent? And indent has more than one meaning: https://www.google.com/#q=indent

Comment: @AlwaysErrors I've indented your code.

Comment: You mean indent within the body of a function/class? Why? I simply didn't feel like it! The code was readable either way. Put more effort into it!

Comment: I'm just going to say what many of us must be thinking. Go learn the basics of C++ first. Learn what classes are how they differ from objects, how to properly write them in C++.

Comment: That's an unusual signature for `main`.  I think the copy-paste was not complete.

Comment: Do not feed the troll.

Comment: I copied and pasted the important parts - I define the parameters of main according to my demands. They have no relevance to whether or not the code will compile.

Comment: also, word of advice, be careful not to step into the realm of 'you have to put effort into answering my question'. People here are not working, we do not have to put of with anything. It is up to you to put the effort in to make your question answerable. If someone says they do not know what you mean, then explain. Trust me, you will find this community a lot more willing to help if you put in effort

Comment: @thecoshman I know the basics of C++!!

Comment: You don't, because you fail to notice that the signature of `main` is plain wrong in your code.

Comment: @AlwaysErrors simply put; no, you do not. You have yet to learn enough to realise how little you really know. C++ is a vast language, and learning even the basics is a non-trivial task. Either stop now or get a GOOD book and start reading.

Answer (score 1):

The function init_sub is declared in the wrong place. It must be moved from the constructor body into the class declaration.

You cannot call that function because it is a non-static member function. It needs an instance on which to call the function. You did not supply one. Either call it on an instance, or make it static.

Your main function also has the wrong signature. It should be

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: Never heard the term "instance method" before. Clarify? I also tried static, and I still can't call it; see above for the error.

Comment: Same as a non-static member function, but instance method is less of a mouthful. Instance method is not common terminology for C++. Still, that function needs a subject and you did not supply one.

Comment: Anyways, my code still is giving me the same original error.

Comment: Then fix it one of the ways that I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The "init_sub" is declared inside the constructor. If you want to call it via class itself, it must be static also.

Comment: I updated, and get the following error: **t.cpp: In constructor 'Buttons::Buttons()':
Line 10: error: 'static' specified invalid for function 'init_sub' declared out of global scope
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.  Please try to indent your code, especially when asking others for help.

Compiling version: http://ideone.com/9lGDvn

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Buttons
{
  public:
  Buttons()
  {
    short pushl;  // unused variable in Constructor: should be a member variable?
    short *tail;  // same
    cout << "Wally Weasel" << "\t";  // Corrected tab character
  };

  ~Buttons()
  {
    cout << "Buttons has been destroyed!";
  }

  static void init_sub(int z, int a);
};

// Note that second argument to main should be char* loc[], one fewer pointer attribute
int main(int args, const char* const LOC[])
{
    int z = 0;
    int a = 1;
    Buttons::init_sub(z, a);
    return 2;
}

void Buttons::init_sub(int x, int y)  // not "Buttons::void"
{
    cout << &x << " " << &y;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same original error as explained above.

Comment: Use copy paste so that you actually run this code. You need to try harder!

Comment: I copied and pasted it, and I still get the same error. @DavidHeffernan Are you attempting to insult me here?

Comment: Always Errors, can you paste the exact error, and then tell us which line in this program is giving you an error?  I included a link to this program compiling and running with an online compiler at ideone.com

Comment: In function 'int main(int, char***)':
Line 27: error: cannot call member function 'void Buttons::init_sub(int, int)' without object
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: I'm not insulting you. But it looks like your clipboard is broken. That's your immediate problem. Then you need to learn to think a little about what you are doing. Programming is hard and requires careful thought.

Comment: Indeed, the signature of your `main(int, char***)` is different from my program, which has `main(int, char**)` (with extra const-ness).